# Expected number of outliers in repeated series of coin tosses

Tags: self-study, binomial-distribution

Out of a theoretical population of $200000$ players who theoretically each play a $1000$ games, each with a chance to win $0.5$, I would like to know how likely it is we see players than win $700$ times or more.

What I did to calculate this is get the chance of winning more than $700$ times, which is in the order of $8 \times 10^{-38}$.

I then took a look at the binomial distribution with $p = 8 \times 10^{-38}$ and $n = 200000$, and concluded that the chance of it happening at least once is in the order of $10^{-32}$, with an expectancy value of the number of times in the same order of magnitude.

I'm being told this is wrong, I'm abusing the central limit theorem, and the expectancy value is about $50-70$.

What am I doing wrong, what is the invalid assumption I'm making, and what is the expectancy value and what is the chance of it occurring at least once?

Answer (score 1):

From your description, players and coin throws are independent and identically distributed. To calculate probability of observing at least $700$ wins for a single player you simply need to look at a [survival function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_function) of [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with parameters $n=1000$ and $p=0.5$. This is the probability of winning $700$ times or more for a single player, let's call it $\pi$.

From here you can easily calculate expected number of winners. Probability that one player will (or will not) be 700-times-or-more-winner is Bernoulli distributed with parameter $\pi$. If you have $200000$ such players, that means that you have multiple Bernoulli trials, so it's again a binomial distribution! What is the expected value of binomial distribution?

Comment: That gives me the 8 * 10 ^ -38. Apparently I'm going wrong with the "easily calculate expected number of winners" part.

Comment: @Martijn see my edit.